# Is it possible to sync all my games to steam from Epic Games Launcher, and Microsoft Store?

Tags: steam, epic-games-launcher

As the title states, is it possible that I could import my games from **Microsoft Store**, **Epic Games Launcher**, into **Steam**, so they can be launched from Steam?

An example is I have **Totally Accurate Battle Simulator** on Microsoft Store because of **Xbox GamePass**, (I have an Xbox too), So is it possible that I can add the game from **Add a non steam game** Feature to add the game?

I tried but could not find the right `.exe` file. Do I have to add it from the **Original** Download location on my PC?
And will it then show up in my steam library?

I would like someone to tell me if it is possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show Non-Steam games as Steam games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326042/show-non-steam-games-as-steam-games)

Comment: Syncing implies another type of merging, though, so can you define that, eShadow? And I don't think Xbox uses .exe files, so I'm not sure that will work.

Comment: If you just want to be able to see and launch all your games from various services in one interface, [GOG Galaxy](https://www.gog.com/galaxy) is a really good start. It does GOG.com, Epic, Steam, UPlay, XBox live, Playstation Network, and Origin so far, and has an interface to expand to support more services in the future. It isn't perfect and if you're like me you may get a reality check when you find out how many games you actually have, but it is really nice to be able to sort and filter your entire game library.

Comment: Ok That is also what I was looking for.. But About achievements, are there going to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer to this is: **it depends on the developer**. It's highly unlikely 'all' games will provide such a key.  For example, Bethesda has provided steam keys to purchasers of Fallout 76 on the Microsoft Store, but Rare has not done so for Sea of Thieves, for two recent examples.

I'm assuming here that you have access to a PC version copy of the game you want to transfer by the way. Console versions will not run on a PC without some extensive modification. (Although; modern consoles are all x86-based; so porting games for them should be easier).

You can of course always add the executable as a *non-steam game* to steam, but you:

- Will not get integration with your profile (achievements etc.)
- May be required to launch additional services to launch the game; Iff it integrates with DRM from the other store(s).

You can use software such as the standard Task manager or the more extensive [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to [figure out the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program) to start the game. Enter that into steam and it should work as a non-steam game.

Answer (score 2):

**[steamsync](https://github.com/jaydenmilne/steamsync)** can import Epic Game Store, Xbox/Windows Store, and itch.io games into Steam (as non-Steam shortcuts).

**[UWPHook](https://briano.dev/UWPHook/)** can import Xbox/Windows Store (GamePass) games into Steam (as non-Steam shortcuts).

**[SteamGridDB Manager](https://www.steamgriddb.com/manager)** could import games from several storefronts, but it looks like the Steam API changed since SteamGridDB Manager's v0.4.2 release so the app fails to function. It's supposed to be fixed in the next release, but there's no ETA and building from source is nontrivial.

You're mostly right that UWP games have no exe. It looks like the way UWPHook works is by adding itself as the exe with the appid as an argument: `"C:\apps\UWPHook.exe" 69C22BB6.MonsterTrain_8ekbzbj4dakee!Game`. steamsync launches them with Windows Explorer: `C:/WINDOWS/explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\69C22BB6.MonsterTrain_8ekbzbj4dakee!Game`. I find that I generally cannot use Steam features in these games -- Steam Input controller support and Steam Overlay don't work. Even if you locate the exe (`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\69C22BB6.MonsterTrain_1.0.12838.0_x64__8ekbzbj4dakee\MonsterTrain.exe`), it includes a version number (1.0.12838) which changes each time the app is updated and that will break your shortcuts.

Achievements and similar stuff won't transfer to Steam (since you don't own the game there). You can use some Steam features like Remote Play, but not other ones like Cloud Saves.

---

Neither of these solutions are as streamlined and complete as GOG Galaxy's integrations -- Galaxy is mostly automatic and even shows your GamePass library with buttons to start an install. However, adding games to Steam allows you to launch them from Big Picture.